# I dont know whats wrong, SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num1 = float(input())
num2 = float(input())

soma = (num1 * 3.5 + num2 * 7.5) / (2 * 10)

print(f'MEDIA = {soma.:5}')
```

...fails with:

```
RUNTIME ERROR
 File "<fstring>", line 1
(soma.)
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: What is the `.` in `soma.:5` intended to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit [this](https://zetcode.com/python/fstring/) link for more info about string formatting in python

```
num1 = float(input())
num2 = float(input())

soma = (num1 * 3.5 + num2 * 7.5) / (2 * 10)

print(f'MEDIA = {soma:.5f}')
```

## Output:

```
$ python3.10 main.py 
3
4
MEDIA = 2.02500
```

Comment: If a question was caused by a typo, it should be closed (with a comment explaining) rather than answered. See the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); the link therein to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; and the bullet point regarding questions caused "by a simple typographical error", which a transposition of characters (`:` and `.` in this case) appears to be.